# can we begin a sentence with "Due to"?

Tags: grammar

> 1. Owing to his illness he could not come to school.
> 2. It was due to his illness he could not come to school
> 3. Due to his illness he could not come to school

I know that the statements 1 and 2 are correct. But what 
about the third one? Is  it acceptable in standard English?

Comment: I don't like the second; the third is better, but I would invert the sentence and say "He could not come to school because of his illness."

Comment: See: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10325/what-is-the-difference-between-owing-to-and-due-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They are all OK.** Although I would add some commas but that is my preference.

In items 2 & 3 we are using **Due** to mean **because of**.So lets do a substitution to see if the sentence is still OK.

It was due to his illness, (that) he could not come to school

It was because of his illness, (that) he could not come to school

Due to his illness, he could not come to school

Because of his illness, he could not come to school

Note; The use of **That** as a conjunction is optional although to me it sounds more comfortable to use **that** in the second example

**that** [Link E.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/that)

> conjunction: used to introduce a clause that reports something or gives further information, although **it can often be left out**:

Answer (score -2):

The second sentence is *not* quite correct (*It was due to his illness **that** he could not...*) and has a strong emphasis on the reason (unlike the other two). In sentence 3 a **comma** is needed after 'Due to his illness'.